# Elimnar un evento programado en android

Tags: java, android

Buenas tardes, estoy programando un `spinner` que sale con una bandera que tengo. si el usuario hace un gesto o un *click* en la pantalla saco un `progressDialog`.

Mi cuestión es como anulo el segundo *click* para que no me haga el evento al cual le di *click* ya trate con el

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

pero con esto ya no me serviría el *segundo click* que muestra el `progressdialiog`.

Estoy tratando de saber como eliminar la pila de eventos que están programados en caso tal que se active la segunda acción. Para capturar el evento estoy utilizando un `dispatchTouchEvent` muchas gracias

Comment: podrias ser un poco mas detallado?, no se entiende que quieres lograr

Comment: Podria ser esto? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195321/remove-an-onclick-listener

Comment: Podrías detallar un poco tu pregunta, al dar clic al spinner se abre un dialogo y donde deseas ya no puedas realizar clic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No entiendo demasiado la pregunta, pero si la idea es activar o desactivar la funcionalidad del boton puedes realizar una instancia del spinner con java mediante un casting a spinner del metodo findviesbyid y entroducirle la id de R.id."el nombre del componente" por parametro. Entonces, el objeto spinner posee el metodo addOnClickListener para agregar eventos, el cual recibe una interfaz por parametro, la cual si es null, no provocara que no haga nada. Si necesitas que no haga nada solo cuando ya se ha pulsado puedes añadirle y elminarle el evento on click con el oyente de foco. Suerte!